Install the new performance tools from Ubuntu 24.04 in 22.04
The release notes state:

A set of performance engineering tools is installed by default on relevant Ubuntu systems. Additionally, a performance-tools metapackage has been created to assist in debugging performance and reliability issues. See specification 168 for more details.

I would like to benefit from this enhancement in Ubuntu 22.04 already. And I wonder if those tools will be added once I will update to 24.04 automatically?
If I just install the packages, that are already available here like this:
sudo apt install procps sysstat iproute2 numactl bpftrace ethtool

Would this speed up my system and do I have to further configure them?

earlyoom is a program that won't improve normal performance, but is very handy when a memory leak happens and the linux kernel poops itself trying to swap out everything and freezes instead of fixing anything.

I misunderstood the point: those tools aren't going to magically improve performance just by being installed. They're being installed by default so that system engineers can more easily monitor performance and understand what configuration needs to be done to improve performance
